# what is the difference between formula and the abbrevation of a formula?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

there is a problem which is asking me to determine whether a string is a formula or an abbrevation of a formula

but i don't know the diffrence of formula and the abbrevation of a formula

i know the definition of a formula , but what about the abbrevation of it ? 
what does it mean ?

how can i get it from a fromula ?

so my question is :

what is the diffrence between formula and the abbrevation of a formula ?

can you give examples to make the diffrence clear ?

Comment: Are you using the Margaris text again?

Comment: @hardmath , yes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will depend entirely on the local conventions of the text you are using. To give a very simple example from propositional logic:

1. Some texts take the basic connectives to be $\neg$ and $\to$, and then introduce $\lor$ with the rule that $(A \lor B)$ is an abbreviation of $(\neg A \to B)$.
2. But another text can take  $\neg$ and $\lor$ as basic, and then introduce $(A \to B)$ as an abbreviation of $(\neg A \lor B)$.
3. Other texts again might have all of $\neg$, $\land$, $\lor$, $\to$ as basic connectives introduced on a par.

As I say, you'll just have to see by inspecting the details of your text whether it counts $(A \lor B)$, for example, as a formula in the official strict sense or merely as a useful 'slang' abbreviation for one.

Answer (score 2):

Rif to :

- Angelo Margaris, [First Order Mathematical Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=q3mObeaklrIC&pg=PA36) (1967 - Dover ed.), **Ex.4**, page 36.

The *terms* of $N$ are [see page 33] :

> the *variables* : $x,y,\ldots$ , the (individual) *constants* : $0,1,2,\ldots$ and all the expressions formed by previous defined terms by means of the operation symbols $+$ ("sum") and $\cdot$ ("multiplication").

The *formulae* of $N$ are [compare with page 31] :

> the *atomic* ones : $(u = v)$ and $(u < v)$, for $u,v$ *terms*, and all those like $\sim P, (P \to Q), \forall vP$, for $P,Q$ previous defined formulae and $v$ a variable.

Thus, the two examples :

> $\forall xy(x+y=y+x)$

amd :

$\exists 0 \forall x(x+0=x)$

are **not** formulae : the first one is an *abbreviation*, while the second one is not well-formed (i.e. it is "un-grammatical").

For the first one, we have that $x+y$ and $y+x$ are *terms* of $N$; thus : $(x+y=y+x)$ is an *atomic* formula. But the "formal" expression of its universal closure must be :

> $\forall x \forall y(x+y=y+x)$.

For the second one, we have that $x+0$ and $x$ are terms, and thus $(x+0=x)$ is an atomic formula.

Also $\forall x(x+0=x)$ is a formula, but $\exists 0 \forall x(x+0=x)$ is not (nor an abbreviation) because the quantifiers use only variables.